# C++ EIGEN: How to create triangular matrix map from a vector?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I would like to use data stored into an Eigen (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org) vector

```
Eigen::Vector<double, 6> vec({1,2,3,4,5,6});
```

as if they were a triangular matrix

```
1 2 3
0 4 5
0 0 6
```

I know how to do it for a full matrix using Eigen's `Map`

```
Eigen::Vector<double, 9>  vec({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9});
std::cout << Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3, RowMajor>>(vec.data());
```

which produces

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

However I do not know how to make a Map to a triangular matrix.

Is it possible?
Thanks!

[Edited for clarity]

Comment: Maybe you could simply transform your vector (write a function that adds the zeroes at proper places) and then give this new vector to `Eigen::Map`.

Comment: Just to make it clear w.r.t. the proposed answers: The reason why this is hard and any solution is unwieldy is because Eigen simply does not support the compressed matrix format for triangular matrices. Therefore any workaround will come at a cost

Comment: Two related feature requests: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/1931, https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion this cannot be done using Map only: The implementation of Map as it is relies on stride sizes that remain constant no matter their index positions, see https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Stride.html.
To implement a triangular matrix map you would have to have a Map that changes its inner stride depending on the actual column number. The interfaces in Eigen do not allow that at the moment, see https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/Map_8h_source.html.

---

But if you are just concerned about the extra memory you can just use Eigen's sparse matrix representation:

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html

(Refer to section "Filling a sparse matrix".)

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to make it clearer. I would like to avoid storing new matrices. I would like to create an Eigen Map. However I do not know if that is possible with a triangular matrix and how to do it.

Comment: I see. IMO this cannot be done with a Map because Maps are constructed using Strides, and Strides only implement the concept of fixed increments in the inner/outer iteration loop. However, it might be possible to sub-class Stride - I have never tried that.

Comment: Subclassing Stride is not an option, also subclassing Matrix would also not work. I have edited my reply accordingly.

Comment: Sparse matrices have a lot of overhead for otherwise dense matrices. Even memory-wise this will probably not be worth it (per entry you need to store the value and an index, even if you used `double` and `int32`, you would need 12 bytes per entry (plus 4 bytes per row or column). That means you would save less than 25% even for large matrices. For `float` matrices you would even require more memory.

Comment: Thanks. Then I will simply create the triangular matrix and copy the entries.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct solution to your problem but a way how to calculate the `std::vector` to fill in the `0` at the correct place. I think it is also possible to calculate it as a `std::array` if needed. I am not sure if that helps, but I guess you could use the calculated vector to fill the `Eigen::Map`

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T, size_t N>
class EigenVector
{
    static constexpr int CalculateRowColSize(size_t n)
    {
        size_t i = 1;
        size_t inc = 1;
        do
        {
            if (inc == n)
            {
                return static_cast<int>(i);
            }
            i++;
            inc += i;
        } while (i < n);
        return -1;
    }

    static constexpr bool IsValid(size_t n)
    {
        if(CalculateRowColSize(n) == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    static_assert(IsValid(N));

public:
    EigenVector() = delete;

    static std::vector<T> Calculate(std::array<T, N> values)
    {
        constexpr size_t mRowColSize = CalculateRowColSize(N);
        std::vector<T> ret;
        auto count = 0;
        auto valueCounter = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < mRowColSize; i++)
        {
            for (auto j = 0; j < count; j++)
            {
                ret.push_back(T());
            }
            for (size_t j = 0; j < mRowColSize - count; j++)
            {
                ret.push_back(values[valueCounter]);
                valueCounter++;
            }
            count++;
        }

        return ret;
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        const std::array<int, 6> arr{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 };

        const auto values = EigenVector<int, 6>::Calculate(arr);

        for (auto& val : values)
        {
            std::cout << val << " ";
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    {
        const std::array<int, 10> arr{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };

        const auto values = EigenVector<int, 10>::Calculate(arr);

        for (auto& val : values)
        {
            std::cout << val << " ";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 0 4 5 0 0 6

1 2 3 4 0 5 6 7 0 0 8 9 0 0 0 10
```

Note that the algorithm is written that only possible matrix sizes are valid as input

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However if I have to create another object, then I'd rather create the triangular matrix directly, in order the make the code more direct, and easier to understand.